# congruent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, transpose

> Show that in $M_3(\mathbb{Z}_7), \begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 3 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \cong \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ but $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \not\cong \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$

I know that to show that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are congruent, it suffices to show that for some invertible matrix $P, A = P^T B P$. However, I am unable to find such an invertible matrix, so I was wondering if it was easier to arrive at a contradiction if I assume that no such matrix exists?

To show that the given two matrices are not congruent, one way (though obviously not very generalizable) is to show that no matrix $P = \begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\end{pmatrix} \in M_3(\mathbb{Z}_7)$ can satisfy that $P^T AP = B,$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ (in this case this works, but it may be harder to show this if such a matrix exists, but it just isn't invertible). One can do so by manipulating a system of equations and showing that there is never a solution (e.g. one can fix a variable $d$ and consider when $d\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$). So I was wondering if there was an easier approach for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the multiplicative inverse of $3$ is $5$ because $15 \equiv 1 \pmod 7.$ While $5$ is not a square, it is the sum of two squares, namely $2^2 + 1^2.$ We want these as columns of $P,$ with the columns obviously having dot product zero, for
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
If the dot product of integer vectors is zero, it is also zero mod 7.

Then
$$  P^T (3I) P $$ comes out nicely

Answer (score 3):

So we are essentially working with quadratic forms: over $\Bbb Z_7$, the quadratic
forms $3x^2+3y^2$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2$ but not to $3x^2+y^2$. These are effectively
quadratic forms in two variables, and as such the first two have square discriminant
and so cannot be equivalent to the third, which has non-square discriminant.

But is you want to bash away with matrices, your equation $P^TAP=B$ implies that
$$\pmatrix{a&d\\b&e}\pmatrix{3&\\&1}\pmatrix{a&b\\d&e}=\pmatrix{1&\\&1}.$$
Taking determinants gives
$$3(ae-bd)^2=1$$
in $\Bbb Z_7$, which is impossible.

Comment: I think you meant $3(ae-bd)^2=1$ in the last equation. And you didn't show how the first quadratic form is equivalent with the second one.

Comment: So if $3x^2 + 3y^2$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2$, can't I find an invertible matrix $P$ that satisfies the definition of congruent matrices?

Comment: @Gord452 It seems as if you were asking two questions (i) that $3x^2+3y^2$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2$ and (ii)  that $3x^2+y^2$ is not equivalent to $x^2+y^2$. I only answered the harder one (ii). For (i) one can just write down an equivalence. It's best to only have one question in a question.

Comment: Two Quadratic forms  in the real Field are equivalent iff their size,rank and signature are equal. In the case of the field Z7 which is not an ordered field how do we define equivalence?